# Create a field that has formatting options in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Basically I need to create a field like the field on stack overflow to ask a question. I am new to Rails and I am wondering if there is a gem that someone could point me to or has a way of doing it from scratch. Basically I need a way to add bold text within the field, Italics, links, ordered lists, and bullet points. Anyways any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use [Trix](https://github.com/basecamp/trix). It's not exactly a gem, but it can be easily used within a Rails Application.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! I will look into that! Looks like it basically just what I'm looking for! :)

Comment: Glad to hear, feel free to "accept" the answer as well :)